# how to include the range header in the GET request?

Tags: http

I want my google chrome to make conditional GET requests.
In other words i want to include the range header:

Range: bytes=100-

In which file do we add this field?

thanks

Comment: my goal is to obtain 206 status response from the server.

Comment: Which tool are you using to generate custom GETs in Chrome?

Comment: used a chrome extension - Change HTTP request header without any success..also is there any way to modify the GET request header fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) Chrome extension to add request headers to REST calls.

It is called **Advanced REST Client** and I was able to add the mentioned header to the GET easily there.

You need just to paste the URL, select **GET**, add the **Header** in one of two available ways (Raw of Form) and click **Send**.

**EDIT:**
[This](http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/) article will surely help you with the 206 response code question.

> Accept-Ranges: bytes
>
> The Accept-Ranges header indicate that the server accept range
> requests for a resource. The unit used by the remote web servers is in
> bytes. This header tell us that either server support download resume
> or downloading files in smaller parts simultaneously so that download
> manager applications can speed up download for you. The Accept-Ranges:
> none response header indicate that the download is not resumable.

I tried the Range header with the following URL from the article and got the 206th response code:
http://s0.cyberciti.org/images/misc/static/2012/11/ifdata-welcome-0.png

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i was not able to replicate the same. I was receiving 200 OK response. I entered the URL as http://google.com and set the range header as Range: bytes=100- . Also i noticed that Accept-ranges:bytes was missing which means the server does not support it?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works! Now this was replicating an issue. Now suppose google chrome does add the range field implicitly there by resulting in 206 response, how do we overcome it and get a 200 OK response?

Comment: You mean the Advanced REST Client adds the header and you want to remove it from your further requests? Or the Google Chrome itself implicitly adds the Range header to each request? If it is the latter, then how did you detect it?

Comment: I googled around a bit about the issue with Chrome adding the Range header, and saw that some people also looking for a way to remove it: [one](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/gIbQovxyqKs) and [two](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/pVhEWkS4hkU). However, I think this is a subject for another discussion...

Comment: Google chrome implicitly adds the Range header to each request. Will check the solutions and get back. Thanks :)

Comment: Unfortunately there were no solutions in those topics. So I suggest creating a new question on StackOverflow to see if someone here has got a solution for your issue. Good luck!

Comment: just did that :) thanks a lot for your quick responses. I actually wanted to replicate the issue before debugging :)